# How to set environment variables in .net interactive

Tags: .net, environment-variables, jupyter

Hey I am trying to set environment variables in my C# jupyter notebook.

I am having difficulty.

I am running .net interactive inside vs codespaces and using the vs code extension.

Is there any way to hide the output of hardcoding a cell and/or set an environment variable.

```
string apiKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("BSER_APIKEY");
```

Would love to be able to read a secret somehow.

https://github.com/dotnet/interactive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since C# can install any package, consider using a `.env` file with the proper environment variables.

```
#r "nuget: dotenv.net, 3.0.0"

using dotenv.net;
DotEnv.Load();
var envVars = DotEnv.Read();
var API_KEY = envVars["XXX_API_KEY"];
```

Your env vars should be accessible through the variable env vars.